# mod_cluster & jboss: out of band garbage collection?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I'm reading about how jboss communicates load factors and lifecycle events to mod_cluster to effectively load balance a cluster. In the ruby on rails world unicorn and passenger 4 do out-of-band garbage collection, where one instance is taken out of the cluster temporarily to do its gc then put back in, so that response latency isnt as affected by gc. Does jboss & mod_cluster do the same thing, or something that is effectively the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...if you are experiencing garbage-collection related problems in your production environment (like, let's say, an absolutely unresponsive system for 10 minutes), you have rather a JVM/application configuration related issue.

mod_cluster, as a smart load balancer, calculates the load on your worker nodes and sends it back to httpd. This load might consist of one or more of these metrics:

- busyness
- heap
- cpu
- requests
- receive-traffic
- send-traffic
- sessions

I would think that an intensive garbage collection would be easily picked up by cpu metric anyhow.

On the other hand...
If you really want to address your garbage collection problem in this fashion, It would be better to have it done via mod_cluster-manager console, where one can temporarily disable a node. As soon as the node is disabled, there won't be any new sessions created on it, so once all sessions are drained, you might have a node without any active requests.

An alternative way would be writing your own load metric that will somehow determine whether the JVM is getting ready for GC and if it is so, it will affect the Load being sending. Yet, I find this being a rather dirty trick.

HTH